# MAC Packges tool shows error for Pre install script

Tags: macos, package

I created a .pkg using Packages tool in Mac. Included a preScript for installing HomeBrew and shows error Don't run this as root.
The script included is:

```
#!/bin/sh
     if test ! $(which brew); then
    echo "Installing homebrew..."
    /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
    fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The script looks fine. Follow the error and try running as normal user and not root. Also, avoid `sudo` before the script.

Comment: The script will work when it is executed using Terminal. but when using Packages tool it shows the error
 Temporarily excluding: /Applications, /Library, /System, /bin, /private, /sbin, /usr
 ./preinstall: Installing homebrew.. ./preinstall: Don't run this as root!